# meaning of 'at medium'

Tags: vocabulary

"And at home, Australia's national terrorism public alert is currently ***at medium*** and has remained unchanged for the last 11 years. ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4077576.htm))"

What meaning does ‘*at medium*’ have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link on [Australia's National Terrorism Public Alert System](http://www.nationalsecurity.gov.au/Securityandyourcommunity/Pages/NationalTerrorismPublicAlertSystem.aspx)

> The National Terrorism Public Alert System is a range of four levels that communicate an assessed risk of terrorist threat to Australia. The four levels are:
>
> - low—terrorist attack is not expected
> - medium—terrorist attack could occur
> - high—terrorist attack is likely
> - extreme—terrorist attack is imminent or has occurred

So, it just means the current level of threat is medium, as defined by this alert system.